How to express the originals system of equation in terms of its Groebner bases?
As a network engineer I need to explain some mathematical stuff to my fellow coleagues. Particularly, I need to explain the fact the the Groebner Basis will create an equivalent system. One particular coleague of mine seems to be very skeptical about it as he thinks it is too good to be true.
I also showing him that the solution of the original system and the GB are similar but he still remain a bit skeptical.
For example: (B) is a GB of (A). Note that this result is obtained by using Mathematica so I guess it is a reduced GB.
$\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{x^2} - 2xy = 0}\\
{{x^2} + 10x + 3{y^2} = 0}
\end{array}\left( A \right) \to } \right.\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{20{y^3} + 7{y^4} = 0}\\
{50x + 15{y^2} - 7{y^3} = 0}
\end{array}} \right.\left( B \right)$
Is there a simple way to show an algebraic manipulation that turn (A) into (B) ?
I try to express equation 1 and equation 2 of (A) as some kind of linear combination of the equation in (B) but I fail.
Please help me with this
Thank you for your enthusiasm !

The existence of Groebner bases is almost too good to be true!  Almost.  For instance, there's a similar situation where it's been proven that certain systems of equations can lead to uncomputable results in terms of trying to compute what identities follow from the equations: look up the "group word problem".

First of all geometrically the solution is a “fat” origin, the intersection of two line pairs through the origin. The method for the intersection of two smooth conics is the same, though. The four points are just squished together in your case.
Gröbner bases more generally are “just” making sure you add generators to an ideal (think polynomial system of equations where it’s the zero set that matters) that degenerate more consistently.
You keep all polynomials in the ideal (combinations of the polynomials you do have) that have leading initial monomials wrt some order.
Mathematica seems to have chosen lex order for you. It’s the most computationally expensive, but gives most information.
I’m sorry to say that the price to pay is to follow the Buchberger algorithm.
In M2
R=QQ[x,y,MonomialOrder=>Lex]
I=ideal(x^2 - 2*x*y, x^2 + 10*x + 3*y^2) 
gens gb I // gens I -- matrix {{(2/3)*x*y+(10/3)*x-y^2+(20/3)*y+100/3, -(2/3)*x+y-35/3}, {-(2/3)*x*y-(10/3)*x+(7/3)*y^2+(20/3)*y, (2/3)*x-(7/3)*y+5}} 
(matrix gens I) * oo -- matrix {{7*y^4+20*y^3, 50*x-7*y^3+15*y^2}}

This means that $$(x^2 - 2xy)(\frac23 xy+\frac{10}3 x-y^2+\frac{20}3 y+\frac{100}3)\\+ (x^2 + 10x + 3y^2)(-\frac23 xy-\frac{10}3 x+\frac73 y^2+\frac{20}3 y) \\= 7 y^4+20 y^3$$ and $$(x^2 - 2xy)(-\frac23 x+y-\frac{35}3)\\+ (x^2 + 10x + 3y^2)(\frac23 x-\frac73 y+5)\\=50x-7y^3+15y^2$$

I am sorry could you explain slowly what just happen. I am just an engineer and I dont received rigorous training in math so I dont understand what is happening ? Currently, I just know of GB as a magic method to simplify system of polynomial equation.

@TuongNguyenMinh Can you read my edit and let me know what you want expanded?

So what to do with these things $ {{(2/3)xy+(10/3)*x-y^2+(20/3)*y+100/3, -(2/3)*x+y-35/3}, {-(2/3)xy-(10/3)*x+(7/3)*y^2+(20/3)*y, (2/3)*x-(7/3)*y+5}}$?

Oh so the strange multipliers are obtained by some sort of polynomial divison right ?

@TuongNguyenMinh The Buchberger algorithm forgb  certainly is. The // operation may be more complicated.

@Jan-MagnusØkland: What does (matrix gens I) * oo do?

@TuongNguyenMinh It’s matrix multiplication of the one by two matrix of generators of the ideal times the two by two of the matrix expressing the relations between those and the generators of the gröbner basis. (It’s what I finally wrote out explicitly in the answer)

Thank you for your guidance !

For a similar calculation in Singular, you could use something like: ring R = QQ,(x,y),(c,lp); module M = [x2-2xy, 1, 0], [x2+10x+3y2, 0, 1]; groebner(M);

How to reproduce the result of Jan-Magnus Økland by using Mathematica ?

@TuongNguyenMinh Maybe this?

Thank you it is very interesting
